# iOS - How to access object properties in an array properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, nsarray, ivar

**Setup:**

`ViewController` holds an `MyArray` of objects from the `PersonClass`.
`PersonClass` has just two properties: `name` and `age`.

**Problem:**

When I want to read out a `name` property from the first object in `MyArray` whats the proper way to do this?

Do I have to temporarily create an instance of `PersonClass` like this?

```
PersonClass *tmp = [PersonClass alloc] init];
tmp = [MyArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", tmp.name);
```

Or can I refer directly to the `properties` of the `objects` in the `MyArray`?

Something like this:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0].name); // not working
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd strongly advise using

```
[(PersonClass *)[MyArray objectAtIndex:0] name]
```

instead of seemingly cleaner, but troublesome form

```
[[MyArray objectAtIndex:0] name]
```

There are two reasons for this. First of all, it's explicit for the reader what gets called on which object. Secondly, it's **explicit for the compiler** - if two methods share the same name, but different return values things can get nasty. Matt Gallagher at Cocoa With Love has an [excellent explanation of this issue.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
PersonClass *tmp = (PersonClass *) [MyArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",tmp.name);
```

Or we can put this on just one line:

```
NSLog(@"%@",((PersonClass *)[MyArray objectatIndex:0]).name);
```

The reason that  `NSLog(@"%@", [self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0].name);` doesn't work is you haven't told the compiler what type of object is at `[self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0]`.  Because it doesn't know what type of object is in your array, there is no way for it to know that it has a `name` property

Comment: I get wanting to maybe make it a one liner, but why decrease the readability? `[[self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0] name]` is much easier to read

Answer (score 0):

```
((PersonClass *)[MyArray objectAtIndex:0]).name
```

or just `[[MyArray objectAtIndex:0] name]`

Comment: "or just" is the killer ;) Thank you.

Comment: It's best *not* to use the second example here - that is not casting -  particularly if you're calling a method rather than a property. The problem is that the compiler has to guess the types of the parameters to the selector. It can get this wrong when two equally-named selectors have different types. See http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to temporarily create an instance of PersonClass like this?
>
> ```
> PersonClass *tmp = [PersonClass alloc] init];
> tmp = [MyArray objectAtIndex:0];
>
> NSLog(@"%@", tmp.name);
> ```

No. Just use

```
PersonClass *tmp = (PersonClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", tmp.name);
```

As the object you are getting from myArray is (or should be!) already alloc'd and init'd before being added to the array. The things in the array are pointers to objects. That's what you are passing around. You have to tell it which type of object you have in there though (the cast is `(PersonClass *)`) because NSArray just stores NSObjects.

You could also do it in one line as thus

`((PersonClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0]).name;`

Comment: The cast here `PersonClass *tmp = (PersonClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];` is completely superflous. Just thought I would mention as you took special care to explain why you did it...

Comment: @Paul.s Good catch. Been doing too much Java recently!

Answer (score 0):

if you want or need the type to be present, then introduce the type like so:

```
PersonClass * person = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

i do this quite regularly for *readability*, and because included files' declarations can otherwise break things.

note that the **cast is not required** when assigning an objc variable from an `id` value.

> Do I have to temporarily create an instance of PersonClass?

No. The program you wrote creates a temporary which is never used.

Comment: `not required when assigning a variable`... from a method with a return type of `id`

Comment: @Paul.s alright - i'll add that. i figured the context was well defined.